# es6 export and import as a whole or destructure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules, destructuring

I was reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export and was playing around but got a question

Let's say I created a function inside a file called `exponential.js`

```
export default (num, exp) => (num ** exp);
```

Then I created a `helper/index.js` which has such below

```
import exponential from './exponential';

export {
    exponential
}
```

which then in other places I can do

```
import { exponential } from './helper';
exponential(2,3);
```

the above works well, but I am trying to see if I can make it to either import as a whole or using the destructuring above so I changed my `helper/index.js`

```
import exponential from './exponential';

export default {
    exponential
}
```

I thought in this way, I can do either

```
import { exponential } from './helper';
exponential(2,3);
```

or

```
import Helper from './helper';
Helper.exponential(2,3);
```

But guess I am wrong, if I use `export default` I can only do the whole import `import Helper from './helper';` using `import { exponential } from './helper';` would give me undefined for the function.

Is there a way that I can actually import both ways?

Sorry if I misread anything in the article and thank you for any advice in advance.

Comment: `import * as Helper from './helper';` would already work with your code as-is, are you aware of that?

Comment: @loganfsmyth ah, great I think I tried this with export default instead of my current and didn't work then thought I tried it on both.  This works great, sryz for such question